# Mochawesome does not generate bulk reports

Tags: testing, cypress, ui-automation, mochawesome

I installed the Mochawesome results reporting add-on to Cypress. The problem is that every time I finish all the tests, I only have the html file with the last one in the reports folder. Do you know how to make a report from the whole set of tests?

However, only one file is created each time, and it is the last one

[image]

and in my cypress.json I have this:

[image]

Code and tests in cypress.json:

```html
{
  "projectId": "fi4fhz",
  "viewportHeight": 1080,
  "viewportWidth": 1920,
  "testFiles": [
    "settings.js",
    "test1.js",
    "test2.js",
    "test3.js",
    "test4.js",
    "test5.js",
    "test6.js",
    "test7.js",
    "test8.js",
    "test9.js",
    "test10.js",
  ],
  "env": {
    "numTestsKeptInMemory": 0,
    "projectUrl": "https://testlocal:6001/",
    "settings": {
      "SP": {
        "tenant": "k.online",
        "clientId": "3a15528c",
        "clientSecret": ".u4L",
        "administrationUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "reporter": "mochawesome",
    "reporterOptions": {
      "charts": true,
      "overwrite": false,
      "html": false,
      "json": true,
      "reportDir": "cypress/report/mochawesome-report"
     },
```

Answer (score 2):

your configuration seems correct, but try to change **reportDir** to **cypress/report** and follow this steps:

1. After running all tests, you should find multiple "mochawesome.json" files, 1 for each spec. To create a single html report, you need one more package.
2. Install **mochawesome-merge** package (npm i mochawesome-merge)
3. Run ***mochawesome-merge "cypress/report/*.json" > mochawesome.json***,  this will create a single JSON file that contains all the tests.
4. Now run the command **marge mochawesome.json** (marge means MochAwesome Report GEnerator) and the *mochawesome-report* directory will be created where there will be an html with all your tests. [Here you can see an example of my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuq19.png)